# What widget constraints are valid for Grails domain classes?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Can you tell me the list of valid values for the [widget constraint](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Constraints/widget.html) below (some-widget), e.g.:

```
static constraints = {
    someField(widget: 'some-widget')
}
```

The documentation seems to be missing. Related, do you know of any plugins that can work directly with this constraint?

Comment: My current goal was to generate a radio button allowing the user to pick one of several values, such as "Pay Now",  "Pay in Increments".  I think this widget constraint could be very powerful and elegant for grails if they did more with it (e.g. with jquery widgets), or if plugins did.  I got a 'radio' choice to work, but only with a boolean type, which won't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look [there](http://hartsock.blogspot.com/2007/08/grails-widget-list.html)

It's an old list, but it's still valid, I think

Comment: I ran into that and didn't really favor it for several reasons: A) it's old (2007!), B) It's not really authoritative (I'd favor it more if the actual source references were in the blog post), and C) There are comments stating that some do not work. I'm hoping for something a bit more concrete.

Comment: When talking about Grails, Shawn Hartsock is authoritative :-) But I see what you mean... Jumping into the code seems to be the only way to figure out that.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean that as a slam on Shawn or anything - I'm just hoping to see some documentation or a definitive list of widgets from the code, or something. I've been digging through the source myself, too, to find it, but have come to a couple dead-ends. Mostly been bouncing around through `renderEditor.template` and `FormTagLib.groovy`.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, the `widget` property is only used for scaffolding and is referenced in the [renderEditor.template](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-resources/src/grails/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template). In that file, it appears that the widget property has some pretty narrow uses depending on the type of object you are scaffolding.

The good news, however, is that you can supply your own `renderEditor.template` file and edit it to work however you want. Just create a file at `${basedir}/src/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template` and Grails will pick it up when you generate the views.

(See [DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-crud/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/scaffolding/DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator.groovy) for more information.)