# Grails Scaffolding Select

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, select, pagination

I have performance issues when i'm using the  tag. In some tables in the database i have thousands of records and when I try to edit some field in Grails the  tag generates a drop-down list of all records in a table and that causes real performance problems and even a EndOfMemorryError sometimes. The generated html is huge, i've tried to implement an autocomplete method for listing but the result wasn't satisfying because  i want this to be a global solution for my 300 Java classes and if i used the autocomplete i had to write it for each one of my classes, now my idea is to try and change the drop-down list with popup windows which display the records using pagination. I beleive i have to change this code in the renderEditor.template:

```
    private renderManyToOne(domainClass,property) {
    if (property.association) {
        def sb = new StringBuilder()
        sb << '<g:select'
        // id is "x" and name is "x.id" as the label will have for="x" and "." in an id will confuse CSS
        sb << ' id="' << property.name << '"'
        sb << ' name="' << property.name << '.id"'
        sb << ' from="${' << property.type.name << '.list(max: 10, offset: offset)}"'
        sb << ' optionKey="id"'
        if (isRequired()) sb << ' required=""'
        sb << ' value="${' << "${domainInstance}?.${property.name}" << '?.id}"'
        sb << ' class="many-to-one"'
        sb << renderNoSelection(property)
        sb << '/>'
        sb as String
    }
}
```

Any ideas will be appreciated :)

Comment: FWIW, there *might* (doubtful, but possible) be an existing [constraint widget](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Constraints/widget.html) that would help you. However, I don't know what the list of possible widgets is. I've [added a bounty to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295811/what-widget-constraints-are-valid-for-grails-domain-classes) to hopefully draw out an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a generic hql for the autocomplete by searching all the fields in your domain classes using the DefautlGrailsDomainClass.getPersistentProperties(). This is probably going to have a terrible performance for big datasets but it would be flexible enough so you won't need to touch one line of your domains nor write specific queries for each domain.

Use **grails install-templates** and modify the templates used for the scaffolding, no need to hack grails code ifself.

Here's the docs: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html

Comment: The `renderEditor.template` he referenced *is* one of the templates.

Comment: I am modifying exactly those templates so that won't do, thanks anyway :)